# How to use better-sqlite3 with electron-react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, electron, better-sqlite3, electron-react-boilerplate

Consider [this](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/issues/126) example created by using the following steps:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate.git better-sqlite3-test
cd better-sqlite3-test
yarn
cd ./release/app
yarn add better-sqlite3
cd ../..
yarn add -D @types/better-sqlite3
```

Now, as soon as I start using the database.js like [this](https://github.com/TechGrizzlee/better-sqlite3-test/blob/main/src/renderer/database.js):

```
class B3SqliteDB {
  constructor() {
    let db = null;
  }

  startDB = () => {
    const Database = require('better-sqlite3');
    this.db = new Database('upStore.db', { verbose: console.log });

    const createTable =
      "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS newTable ('id'  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 'name'  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);";

    this.db.exec(createTable);
  };
}
export default new B3SqliteDB;
```

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Database is not a constructor
    at B3SqliteDB.startDB (renderer.dev.js:65346)
    at renderer.dev.js:65285
```

Can someone please help to figure this out! TYA

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

- Downgrade electron to 13.6
- Install better-sqlite3 in root
- Rebuild the package
- Test

```html
yarn remove electron
yarn add electron@13.6.1
yarn add better-sqlite3; 
cd node_modules/better-sqlite3; 
../.bin/electron-rebuild
cd ../..
npm run start
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1mS4.png)

Note

- You can try other desktop options (Electron Alternatives) that support integration ReactJS | VueJS just fine

1. Wails (Golang)
   https://github.com/wailsapp/wails
2. Lorka (Golang)
   https://github.com/zserge/lorca
3. Tauri (Rust)
   https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri
4. Flutter Desktop (Dart)
   https://flutter.dev/desktop

- What I love is that the app size is just 10 - 20 times smaller than a sample Hello World Electron App.